# Create a script to create a link which is a modified version of the current URL

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a site with sequential page naming.
Take the below as an example

- mysite.com/index.html
- mysite.com/book-1.html
- mysite.com/book-2.html

I want to create a button that runs a script to get the current URL and increment the number after "book-" by 1. This would effectively be used as a "Next Page" button. I want to avoid using hard coded links because the real site has over 900 pages. This would be useful since I would simply need to copy a single snippet of code to on to each page as opposed to taking the time to manually change each and every link.

To do this i plan on using JS to:

1. get the URL of the current web page
2. split up the text string by the  "-"  character
3. increment the number after the "-" character by 1
4. concatenate the term "www.mysite.com/book-" and the newly evaluated number from step 3

I then want to use this resulting concatenated text string as the value for the href attribute of an   HTML tag....  it should look something like the following:

```
<a href="*concatenated string from step 4*" >
```

What would be the simplest javascript code to use for steps 1-4 and what is the correct syntax to be used inside the  tag so that the hyperlink would point to the URL generated in step 4 (the concatenated string)?

Comment: Give it a go, then come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Since you're creating a HTML page for each book.  Why wouldn't you just put the link manually?  For instance on book1.html, you could just put the link for "book2.html", in my opinion you're over thinking it.

Comment: I have about 900 pages, and if I can have the next page to be a calculated value as opposed to manually hard coding 900 links I thought I could save myself some time...not sure why the negative rep..

Comment: @Xero Think about the amount of work when OP wants to move the book2 after book860.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see in your question that you had that many pages, I assumed you only had 3, as listed.

Comment: it's alright... I really just wanted to offer an easy example in my original post.. believe me, if my site was only 4 pages large I wouldnt be here..

Comment: @Harif87 You're getting downvotes, since the answer to your question is simply "yes". You're not having a __specific__ programming problem. Please describe the hard part, getting the current URL? Splitting it to parts? Show what you've tried, and explain what it does instead of what you want it to do. Then you have a question.

Comment: Teemu, thanks for the constructive criticism  - I'm not such a frequent poster here, so thanks for cluing me in.... i'll rethink my question and repost

Comment: @Harif87 I hope you meant you will edit your post. Asking the same question again is bad as well.

Answer (score 2):

My answer basically gets the URL, splits it, then gets the number of the book on the current URL then adds 1 to it, then sets the `href` attribute to the next book...

Although, I clearly don'y have a URL you your website,  So where the comment is, replace the string with `document.URL`...  This has a vault of the current URL (which obviously isn't your website.)

```
var URL = "http://example.com/book3.html"; // Replace this with document.URL in your actual script

var URL_split = URL.split("/");
var URL_return_num = parseInt(URL_split[URL_split.length - 1].replace(/book(.*?)\.html/i, "$1"));

document.getElementById("next_book").setAttribute("href", "book"+(URL_return_num+1)+".html");
```

---

I will run through what this actually does.

`var URL`: this stores the URL for future use in the script.

`var URL_split`: This changes the `URL` into an array, for each "/" in the text.

`var URL_return_num`: This is a quite compact one.  This basically fetches the last part of the split URL which is "book3.html"...  It removes the "book" and the ".html" with regex.  Then it turns it into an int, so it can be added to.

`"book"+(URL_return_num+1)+".html"`:  This creates a string, basically saying `"book" + (current_book_number + 1) + ".html"`, in this case (on the page), it would be `"book" + (3+1) + ".html"`

---

Here is a JSFiddle example, although it's not much use because it's not on your website.
http://jsfiddle.net/XeroElixir/Uwg7n/1/

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work...  After all I don't have access your your site.